# Сохранить изображение, изменённым с помощью imagecopyresampled размером

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать копию изображения меньшего размера. Достал из мануала код.

```html
// файл
$filename = 'newimage/9204.jpg';

// задание максимальной ширины и высоты
$width = 200;
$height = 200;

// тип содержимого
//header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// получение новых размеров
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

// ресэмплирование
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

//imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);

move_uploaded_file($image_p, 'newimage/$image_p');
```

Указания в мануале завершающая функция `imagejpeg()`, но мне нужно сохранить сгенерированное изображение в директорию, как это сделать?

Comment: В imagejpeg вторым аргументом укажите путь для сохранения

Comment: Anton Kucenko ,благодарю.